# Convert rows to string on SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table on Sql:

```
ID    User       Observation
========================================
1     John       This is correct!
----------------------------------------
2     Michael    I got an error!
----------------------------------------
3     Joshua     This is incorrect!
----------------------------------------
```

What I want is a function thar returns a varchar With the data on a string

Like this:

**Edit:** 
This is the result I expect:

```
John says: This is correct!\r\nMichael says: I got an error!\r\nJoshua says: This is incorrect
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I've tried using a cursor but I don't want to do it that way

Comment: So you want everything in a single column?

Comment: Yes I do on single column and single row

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a single column and a single row you can do this

```
DECLARE @out as varchar(max)

SET @Out = ''

SELECT @Out = @Out +  [User] + ' says: ' + Observation + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)  
FROM Table1

SELECT @out
```

[See it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7b71/4)

here's the output in SSMS (using text output)

```
-------------------------------
John says: This is correct!
Michael says: I got an error!
Joshua says: This is incorrect!

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Out has many rows if the table has many rows.. I want only ONE row containing all the data.

Comment: um no it gives back one row with line breaks. that's what CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) does. Also `SELECT @out` can't ever return more than one row

Answer (score 4):

If you want to concat all rows separated by a carriage-return+new-line:

```
declare @UserObservation Table(ID int, [User] varchar(20), Observation varchar(100));
insert into @UserObservation values(1, 'John' ,'This is correct!');
insert into @UserObservation values(2, 'Michael' ,'I got an error!');
insert into @UserObservation values(3, 'Joshua' ,'This is incorrect!');

DECLARE @WhatAllUserSay VARCHAR(8000) ;
SELECT @WhatAllUserSay = 
    COALESCE(@WhatAllUserSay + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '') + [User] + ' says: ' + Observation 
FROM @UserObservation

PRINT @WhatAllUserSay;
```

[`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Output:

```
John says: This is correct!
Michael says: I got an error!
Joshua says: This is incorrect!
```

Comment: But this give me many rows containing strings.... what I want is a single row with all the data separating rows by a break line.

Comment: Please give an example of the EXACT output you require, then people will be able to help you (or at least tell you confidently that its not possible).

Comment: Updated... That is te result I expect

Comment: nice use of COALESCE to avoid initing the string.

Comment: COALESCE is not required in fact if you initialize your VARCHAR with ''. Great trick with ~"SELECT @WhatAllUserSay += nextUserSays FROM MultipleRowTable". I always thought that the only way to concatenate string from different rows is by using CURSOR and loop. Very very useful.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT [User] + ' says: ' + [Observation] FROM [TableName]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT User +' says: ' + Observation AS USER_SAID
FROM TABLE;
```